# Javascript : toFixed function return NaN when take 0 as input

Tags: javascript, percentage, zero, tofixed

I'm implementing toFixed function with dynamic input data, data my be zero in some cases so the function return Nan:

```
result.options.forEach(option => {
  option.percentage = ((option.number / result.votersNb) * 100).toFixed(2);
});
```

**How can I handle when percentage result is zero !**

Comment: If you type `(0).toFixed(2)` into your browser console you'll see that it does not return `NaN`.

Comment: Divide by zero?

Comment: In your calculation are you sure that option is a valid object and that .number and .votersNb are numbers ?

Comment: @phuzi That'd return "Infinity".

Comment: @Adriani6 `0/0` => NaN

Comment: @Adriani6 is right. Is it possible that the `option` or `result` objects are invalid then?

Comment: @phuzi Ah, I assumed the right hand number is 0 :) You only said "divide by" 0 not both numbers are 0 :P

Comment: I guess maybe options.number or result.votersNb is a string, so the division operation makes an NaN. You should carefully check the data types.

Comment: @Adriani6 probably should have been more specific ;o)

Comment: Modify your loop to check option, option.number, result and result.votersNb for valid types and values before use.

Comment: option.number and result.votersNb are both 0 but when I type   console.log((option.number/result.votersNb) * 100) I got NaN

Comment: @sahnoun That's because 0/0 returns NaN.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert to `Number` and use `toFixed` method.

```js
[0, null, undefined, Infinity, 4, 55.6666].forEach(x =>      console.log(Number(x).toFixed(2)));
```